# Why parents tabsshow-event triggered by childtab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a tab (called firsttab) with in his content another tab (called childtab). We bind the tabshow-event to the firsttab.

If we click to one of the tabs in "firsttab" all work fine (Tab 1 - Tab 5).
If we click to one of the "childtab" tabs (Tab 1.1 - Tab 1.3) the tabshow-event who are bind to the "firsttab" is triggerd.

Testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/bM8Wh/

HTML:

```
<div id="firsttab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#firsttab_1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#firsttab_2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#firsttab_3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#firsttab_4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#firsttab_5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="firsttab_1">
        <div id="childtab">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#childtab_1">Tab 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#childtab_2">Tab 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#childtab_3">Tab 1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <div id="childtab_1">Tab 1.1</div>            
            <div id="childtab_2">Tab 1.2</div>
            <div id="childtab_3">Tab 1.3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="firsttab_2">Tab 2</div>
    <div id="firsttab_3">Tab 3</div>
    <div id="firsttab_4">Tab 4</div>
    <div id="firsttab_5">Tab 5</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#firsttab, #childtab").tabs();
$("#firsttab").bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { funcX(ui.index); });
  
function funcX(idx){
    alert('triggerd - index: ' + idx);
}
```

I don't understand why the tabsshow-event is triggered by the childtab because I bind this event to the firsttab.

The answer of my jQuery-ticked was:

> "Events bubble; check the target."

but I don't understand what it means.

I handle the problem by change my tabsshow-event-handler to:

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsshow',
  function(event, ui) {
    if ((/#(.*?)$/im).exec(ui.tab.hash)[1] == this.id)
      funcX(ui.index);
  });
```

but I will understand where are the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [event's bubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), meaning that an event in a child element goes up to all parent elements unless you stop it.  So for example a click anywhere on the page is a `click` event on that element, it's parent, and so on up until `document`.  This behavior also happens with any custom jQuery events like `tabsshow`, but if you don't want it you can stop the event from bubbling using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$("#childtab").bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { 
  event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

This stops the event from firing on `#firsttab` because it just doesn't bubble up there anymore.  [You can try your sample with this fix here](http://jsfiddle.net/bM8Wh/1/).

Comment: ok i think i understand. the tabsshow-event form the childtab are not handled so it will be goes up to the parent element until the tabsshow-event is handled by the firsttab-eventhandler.

but is it not "stupid" by jquery to fire events to an eventhandler wo has not bind to this? wouldt not jquery handel this mistake? i bind my eventhandler to firsttab.tabshow-event not to firsttab_and_all_childs.tabshow.event and in my opinion jquery should only fire the event if his referer the target excpect i bind the eventhandler with an "takeallchildevent"-option.

Comment: a second question: in your solution you bind a second eventhandler to the childtab. but is it not a better solution to bind it to all tabs like:

$("DIV.ui-tabs").bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { event.stopPropagation(); });

Comment: @floyddotnet - *All* events bubble, even if they're handled they continue to bubble, unless you `return false` or `.stopPropagation()`, this is just how the DOM is *expected* to work (with or without jQuery).  For your second comment yes that's a perfectly valid approach, just make sure to run that *after* creating the tabs, otherwise they don't have the `ui-tabs` class added to them yet.  Any selector that finds the element and binds a handler to stop propagation will work :)